# Função de retorno true retorna false em uma expressão Vue

Tags: javascript, data, vue.js-2, momentjs

Eu criei um método que serve para tirar a diferença de uma determinada data com a data de hoje. Com o código que eu coloquei, ela retorna `true`. Mas, quando vou usa-la dentro de um valor computado, ela retorna `undefined`. E no valor computado eu faço uma condicional que de qualquer forma vai retornar `true` mas, quando vou usá-la como uma expressão no Vue, ela retorna false.

```html
<template>
    <p v-if="dataqualquer">Hello World</p>
</template>

<script>
    computed: {
        dataqualquer() {
            const data = this.dataDiferenca("05/02/2018")
            data ? true : true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        dataDiferenca(data) {
           // console.log(data)
           // data = data.split("/")
           // data.reverse();
           // data = data.join("-")
           // data = this.moment(data)
           // console.log(data.diff())

           // data.diff() < 0 ? false : true
           data = data.split("/");
           data.reverse();
           data = data.join("-")
           data = new Date(data)

           const hoje = new Date()

           data - hoje < 0 ? false : true
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esqueceu de dar `return` no seu método `dataDiferenca` e no valor computado `dataqualquer`

```js
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    computed: {
        dataqualquer () {
            const data = this.dataDiferenca("05/02/2018")
            return data
        }
    },
    methods: {
        dataDiferenca (data) {     
           data = data.split("/");
           data.reverse();
           data = data.join("-")
           data = new Date(data)

           const hoje = new Date()

           return data - hoje < 0 ? false : true
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p v-if="dataqualquer">Hello World</p>
</div>
```